# ng-if showing element that has false expression

Tags: angularjs

Why is this element showing? I've tried it on values from the component too.

```
<div ng-if="1 == 2">
  <p>File uploaded.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried most simple one? ng-if="false"

Comment: Check, maybe you have errors in console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your spelling is wrong and you forgot the asterisk.

You need to do:

```
<div *ngIf="1 == 2">
  <p>File uploaded.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If its angular2 it should be **[`*ngIf`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgIf-directive.html)**,

```
<div *ngIf="1 == 2">
  <p>File uploaded.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Previous answers are right, only posting here to notify you about the '==' you are using.

I would use '===' instead as it is more appropriate but just in case you don't know, both expressions are correct but don't compare the exact same thing :

The operator '==' check equality when '===' check type and equality

With a basic example :

- 0 == '0' would be true
- 0 === '0' would be false